# How can i remove the undefined value in selected list

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my code

```
    if ($("option:contains('" + data.strRoundName + "')").length == 0)
        $("#selectRound_Type").append("<option name='round' id=" + data.iRoundId + ">" +             data.strRoundName + "</option>");
```

PFB my output screen(getting undefined value)

[image: getting undefined value]

Comment: make sure there is something in `data.strRoundName` that is why this problem is ocurring.

Comment: may be your reaching array out of bound

Comment: Check your loop as @dreamweiver said :) If you have something like
 i <= array.length, maybe changing it to i < array.length

Comment: PFB what does PFB mean? And where is your testcase?

Comment: its just Please fine below (PFB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : filter all option which is having text == undefined and remove it.

```
$("#selectRound_Type").find('option').filter(function(){
     return $(this).text()=="undefined";
}).remove();
```

OR check `undefined` while adding options using below code

```
if ($("option:contains('" + data.strRoundName + "')").length == 0 
       && data.strRoundName != null 
       && typeof data.strRoundName != "undefined")
        $("#selectRound_Type").append("<option name='round' id=" 
             + data.iRoundId + ">" 
             + data.strRoundName + "</option>");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if ($("option:contains('" + data.strRoundName + "')").length == 0){
    if (typeof(data.strRoundName) != "undefined" && data.strRoundName != null) {
        $("#selectRound_Type").append("<option name='round' id=" + data.iRoundId + ">" + data.strRoundName + "</option>");
    }    
}
```

Comment: this `data.strRoundName !== null` should be `data.strRoundName != null`, remove extra `=` sign.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ($("option:contains('" + data.strRoundName + "')").length == 0) {
    if(data.strRoundName)
        $("#selectRound_Type").append("<option name='round' id=" + data.iRoundId + ">" + data.strRoundName + "</option>");
}
```

Comment: This is likely to be a good way to simply mask the problem rather than fixing it. Don't.

Comment: If `data.strRoundName` is undefined then it will not append the element. Is that not correct?

Comment: You're not listening to me.